# How insert image while echoing according to category?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration form and that goes to database. Some categories are there to select in the registration form. While registering he want to select one category mandatory. For example he select "travel". And this category will save into database under category. And there is a page to echo these things. While echoing I want to display an image according to the category. If "travel" one particular image, if "political" another image etc.etc... Please help. These images want to store inside database or local directory?

Comment: to be completely flexible, save the images in the local directory and the according path in the database (table Categories: id, name, imgsrc).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a folder that will contain all your images and in the category table your structure it like this

```
Id | Title  | Image
1  | Travel | travel.jpg
```

than when you want to echo the image just create an img tag and use the name from the databse

```
<img src="/img/categories/<?php echo $categoryName ?>" />
```

HTH

Comment: Ok...Thanks...i think this will work...How i enter "travel.jpg" to database?

Comment: Well do you have some sort of database management software like phpMyAdmin or MySQL workbench. Just create the image field in the categories table and added the values manually. The values must match the actual filename in the filesystem.

Comment: There are 5 to 8 fields to add by a customer in the registration page. One is category. Its a drop down menu.

Comment: Forget the website and code for now ... do you have a table in your database that stores the categories?

Comment: great can you list the fields of that table pleaes? We need to add an image field there of type varchar(50) NOT NULL

Comment: "id_user INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,".
"org VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,".
"pgmtitle VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,".
"category VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL ,".
"relation VARCHAR( 75 ) NOT NULL ,".
"time VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,".
"day1 VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,".
"city VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL ,".
"others VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL ,".
"contactperson VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
"contactnumber VARCHAR( 128 ) NOT NULL ,".
"email VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,".
"nature VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,".
 "resentry VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,". "PRIMARY KEY ( id_user )".

Comment: I disagree with your table structure this is not in 3 normal form. This table you posted should contain a foreign key for the category ... therefor this table instead of category should have field named category_id of type INT(11) .... which would link to the categories table with the fields id , title and image. When building your registration form you would query the table categories {SELECT * FROM categories} and use that resultset to build your drop down. The value of the option would be the id of that table ... upon submitting the form you use that id to save it to the table here posted.

Comment: $today = date('D, d M, Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE day1 = '$today' AND city = 'Japan'";
if($_POST!=""){
$mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['datepicker']);
 if($mydate!=""){ 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM programs WHERE day1 = '$mydate' AND city = 'Japan'"; 
 }  
    }
This is the query.....

Answer (score 0):

Store the images on file system and not in the database. One possible option to display images could be to name your images according to the category IDs present in the database. so if the categoryID for "travel" is '1' then rename the "travel.jpg" image to "1.jpg" and so on. Then using php display that category image.